# I made a stopwatch project but the counter displays 00:00:00 even when clicking the start button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is the code That i wrote and got some help from chatgpt I tried asking multiple Ai about how to solve this issue but none of them solved it...

```py
import tkinter as tk
from time import gmtime, strftime

class Stopwatch:
    def __init__(self, root):
         # Initialize the Stopwatch class with a tkinter root window
         self.root = root
        self.root.title("Stopwatch: By Suhail")

        # Initialize variables to manage the stopwatch state
        self.running = False
        self.start_time = 0
    
        # Create a tkinter StringVar to update the label text
        self.label_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_var.set("00:00:00")
    
        # Create a tkinter Label to display the stopwatch time
        self.label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.label_var, font=('calibri', 40, 'bold'), background='white', foreground='black')
        self.label.pack(anchor='center')
    
        # Create Start and Reset buttons with associated functions
        self.start_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command = self.start_stopwatch)
        self.start_button.pack(side='left', padx=10)
    
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", command = self.reset_stopwatch)
        self.reset_button.pack(side='right', padx=10)
    
    def start_stopwatch(self):
        # Function to start or stop the stopwatch
        if not self.running:
            # If the stopwatch is not running, start it
            self.running = True
            self.start_time = gmtime() - self.start_time
            self.start_button.config(text="Stop")
            self.update_stopwatch()
        else:
            # If the stopwatch is running, stop it
            self.running = False
            self.start_button.config(text="Start")
    
    def reset_stopwatch(self):
        # Function to reset the stopwatch
        self.running = False
        self.start_time = gmtime()
        self.start_button.config(text="Start")
        self.update_display()
    
    def update_stopwatch(self):
        # Function to update the stopwatch time
        if self.running:
            elapsed_seconds = gmtime() - self.start_time
            self.label_var.set(strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(elapsed_seconds)))
            self.root.after(1000, self.update_stopwatch)
        else:
            self.update_display()
    
    def update_display(self):
        # Function to reset the display when the stopwatch is not running
        self.label_var.set("00:00:00")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a tkinter root window and an instance of the Stopwatch class
    root = tk.Tk()
    stopwatch = Stopwatch(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

When running the code i expected that when hitting the Start Button it would start Counting the milli seconds and after reaching 1000 it adds to the seconds counter 1s and after 60s adds 1m and so on...

Comment: line 53, in update_stopwatch
    self.label_var.set(strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(elapsed_seconds)))
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'gmtime'

Comment: Typo error `type herimport tkinter as tk` should be `import tkinter as tk`. Please fix the indensation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: Note that `gmtime()` returns a `time.struct_time` object which cannot be subtracted by an integer, so exception should be raised on the line `self.start_time = gmtime() - self.start_time` inside `start_stopwatch()`.  Use `time.time()` instead of `gmtime()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in line:

```
self.label_var.set(strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(elapsed_seconds)))
```

Instead use:

```
self.label_var.set(strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(elapsed_seconds)))
```